# Hangfire updates to table causing TransactionInDoubtException

Tags: .net, hangfire

Recently we started using Hangfire to run more and more asynchronous jobs.

We have 1 job for invoicing that loops through all of out locations and uses ContinueJobWith to create 1 Job for each location. (This is maybe around 100)

Then that job uses ContinueJobWith to create 1 job for EACH customer at that location to create their monthly invoice and charge them.

Are we improperly chaining these jobs to cause these locks/timeouts that throw the TransactionInDoubtException?

This is the SQL statement throwing that error

`update top (?) JQ set FetchedAt = GETUTCDATE() output INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.JobId, INSERTED.Queue, INSERTED.FetchedAt from [HangFire].JobQueue JQ with (forceseek, paglock, xlock) where Queue in (? and (FetchedAt is null or FetchedAt < DATEADD(second, ? GETUTCDATE()))`

We are using Hangfire 1.7.2

This is an example of how we enqueue the next job:

`jobId = BackgroundJob.ContinueJobWith<Invoice>(jobId, e => e.NewJob(parameters), JobContinuationOptions.OnAnyFinishedState );`